# UTF-8 with Azure web job using java

Tags: java, azure, azure-webjobs

We are facing issue with Arabic character in data.
when we run java application which is for Google analytics in local with eclipse IDE with UTF-8 encoding or without encoding data comes perfectly.

like below:-
20108^^665328^^عالم فيراري, أبوظبي^^اماكن سياحيه في دبي^^اماكن سياحية في دبي^^Tourism Dubai^^Campaign^^KSA |

But when we run same application as webjob we are getting issue and data in not coming perfectly and data is

like below:-
20170106^^(not set)^^(not set)^^??? ??? ?????????^^(not set)^^(not set)^^Campaign^^(not set)

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = directory.getBlockBlobReference(fullReportName);
blob.getProperties().setContentType("text/plain");
blob.getProperties().setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
blob.uploadText(String.join("\n", csvContent));
```

**Note:- We have application to fetch data from Google Analytics which brings data into Azure blob in csv format.**

Thanks,
Sudeep Thakur

Comment: could you share your code please ?

Comment: CloudBlockBlob blob = directory.getBlockBlobReference(fullReportName);
blob.getProperties().setContentType("text/plain");
blob.getProperties().setContentEncoding("UTF-8");   blob.uploadText(String.join("\n", csvContent));
@Thomas

Comment: Add your code to your question, it will be easier for people to understand your problem. Mu tough is that the problem appear before you upload the csvContent. How do you get your csvContent ? Could you add logging to see if the csvContent is ok before uploading ?

Comment: Added note in question.
Yes while writing to azure blob storage.

Comment: Can you add logging before sending the csv ?? are you sure the csv is ok before the upload ?